# parsing json array which is stored in database

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, model-view-controller

```
    string json = db.PurchasedOrders.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==2013).PurchasedItem;
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<purchasJsonObject>>(json);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {

                PurchasedOrderDetail details = new PurchasedOrderDetail()
                {


                    ItemId = item.Id,
                    Quantity = item.qty,
                    Rate = item.Price,
                    TotalAmount = (item.qty * item.Price),
                    Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(po.CashDiscount),
                    ExtraItem = 0,
                    SlNo = 0,
                    ReceiveQty = 0,

                };
                _db.PurchasedOrderDetails.Add(details);


            }
            _db.SaveChanges();


----------
```

trying retrive json data from database and parse it and add in another table "PurchasedOrderDetail". but when i execute the code PurchasedOrderDetail table remains empty... can u please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Does the `list` contains any items? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Possibly also worth posting your json content for PurchasedItem (from the PurchasedOrder with Id = 2013)